# Wpf EventTrigger not firing at some elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I have something like this, `ListView` and `Button`. `ListView` also have two `Buttons`. The main idea is to click on `Button` in the `ListView` to disabled `TestButton`.
After click `TestButton` do not changing but `TestButton2` changing. why?

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="200" Width="200">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Content="Test" Grid.Column="0" Height="20" Width="20">
                        <ei:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <ei:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <i:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="TestButton" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="False"></i:ChangePropertyAction>
                                <i:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="TestButton2" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="False"></i:ChangePropertyAction>
                            </ei:EventTrigger>
                        </ei:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="TestButton2" Content="Test2" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="20"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<string> Items {get;set;}
    public Data()
    {
        Items= new List<string>();
        Items.Add("Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Trigger` doesn't fire because `TestButton` defined outside of the `ListView`'s `VisualTree`. To make this work, you can define a Boolean Property in code behind and set it as `TargetObject` of your `EventTrigger` and also the binding-source of `IsEnabled` property of your `TestButton`.

Code behind (*with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented*):

```
    bool _btnIsEnable;
    public bool ButtonIsEnable
    {
        get
        {
            return _btnIsEnable;
        }
        set
        {
            _btnIsEnable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ButtonIsEnable");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ButtonIsEnable = true;
    }
```

The second `ChangePropertyAction` should change like this:

```
<i:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=.}
        "PropertyName="ButtonIsEnable" Value="False"/>
```

And the binding for `TestButton` should look like this:

```
<Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Button" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonIsEnable}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```